# Finding velocity of a particle in linear motion.

Tags: calculus, kinematics

> In a kinematics question of linear motion I have been given a function between velocity$(v)$ and time$(t)$.
>   $v=(t-1)(t-2)$
>   and that for $t=0$, position of particle is $+4$.
>   Now I have to find its velocity at origin.

I integrated $v$ and got a cubic equation. Now I'm unable to solve. Is there any  way to solve this problem?

Comment: If you integrated you know you would have a constant of integration, $C$, that needs to be dealt with.  Do you have anything in your problem that you haven't used yet?

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven-C can be found out using the given initial position.

Comment: Yes.  obviously the posts below show you how.  I was trying to give you a hint before someone answered.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find for what $t$ the position is $0$.

integrating $v$ gives us position;

$s = \displaystyle\int(t-1)(t-2)\,dt = \int (t^2-3t+2)\,dt = \frac{t^3}3-\frac32t^2+2t+C$

given that $s(0) = 4$

$\implies 4 = C$

$\therefore s(t) = \displaystyle\frac{t^3}3-\frac32t^2+2t+4$

To find at what $t$ position is zero set $s(t) =0$

$s(t) =0 =\displaystyle\frac{t^3}3-\frac32t^2+2t+4$

The above is not easily solvable and you can find the solution using numerical methods . The only real solution is $x \approx -1.03$

So the velocity at origin is given by;

$v(-1.03) = (-1.03-1)(-1.03-2)= 6.1509$

Comment: @TheIntegrator- Is there a simpler way as this was given by my teacher to solve in class. I dont think he will give such a question which can't be done manually.

Comment: @LoveInvariants i dont think so , the cubic isnt easily factorable . numerical methods are your best bet

Comment: @TheIntegrator- Some times when their roots are of form $m+m^{2/3}+m^{1/3}$ or they have integral root.

Comment: @LoveInvariants i do not get what you mean

Comment: @TheIntegrator- there is a method to find cubic roots of the form $m+m^{2/3}+m^{1/3}$ eg. $3+3^{2/3}+3^{1/3}$

Comment: @LoveInvariants That method would not work here as it is not of that form.Perhaps you should ask your teacher and clarify whether the given question was correct or not

Comment: I may ask for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
\dot{x}(t) = (t-1)(t-2) \\
x(0) = 4
$$
This gives
\begin{align}
4 - x(t) 
&= \int\limits_{t}^0 (\tau-1)(\tau-2)\, d\tau \\
&= [(1/3)(\tau-1)^3-(1/2)(\tau-1)^2]_{\tau=t}^{\tau=0} \\
&= (1/3)(-1)-(1/2)-(1/3)(t-1)^3+(1/2)(t-1)^2
\end{align}
so
$$
x(t) = (1/3)(t-1)^3-(1/2)(t-1)^2+29/6
$$

[image: sketch]
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCAdW.png))

We have
$$
x(-1) = (1/3)(-8)-(1/2)4+29/6 = (-16-12+29)/6 = 1/6 \approx 0
$$
and
$$
\dot{x}(-1)=6
$$
With $m=2$ this estimates the kinetic energy at $x=0$ as
$$
T = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 \approx 36
$$

Comment: Is there no simpler way? To get precise value without solving the equations using computer

Comment: @Mvw- thanks, I can't accept the answer(Its not a perfect answer) but I upvoted it.

Comment: but position of particle isn't at origin at t=0

Comment: You should also consider the fact that it is a problem of straight line motion, and I had to find its kinetic energy at origin.

Comment: "Given that at initial instant, position is +4m then find kinetic energy of the particle when it is crossing origin if its mass is 2kg." -Are the exact words of the question

Comment: Oops, it is 4 metre